# Bittorent Rarest First algorithm - how are pieces selected?

Tags: algorithm, bittorrent

I was reading up on the rarest first algorithm:

> For efficiency, PWP uses a simple strategy called rarest first in
>   which, given the current list of missing pieces, the client requests a
>   rarest one first (i.e. a **piece** which fewest -- but non-zero -- of its
>   neighboring peers have). Typically, there are many pieces which are
>   equally rare. In this case it is also important to randomly pick one
>   of them to download. This way, the availability of pieces are spread
>   out and thus even when all seeders go to heaven, chances are better
>   that no piece goes extinct.

**My question is: what happens when two pieces have the same rarity?** Do we select the piece of which fewer blocks have been downloaded, or do we select one at random? The text says we select one at random, but I'm not sure how that's any better than the former strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rarest first algorithm selects which pieces to *start*. So once you have enough incomplete pieces in progress you usually don't need to run the algorithm again (except for the case where a peer has nothing to offer for in-progress pieces).

So if there already is a piece in progress (rarest or not) then you generally want to complete that piece first and the question does not arise. If for whatever reason you do need to start a new piece than random choice is a good default strategy.

There are some more exotic strategies such as coarser-than-piece-size selection to create more HDD-friendly IO patterns in high throughput scenarios, but that's an edge-case.

A more important deviation from rarest-first arises when you're implementing the [Fast Extension](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0006.html) where you may want to choose pieces from the allowed fast set or suggested pieces in addition to or instead of rarest pieces.